# Server 2012 Backup Retention Settings & Schedule

Tags: nas, windows-server-2012, windows-backup, synology

I am using Windows Server 2012 Datacenter x64 as my File Server.
I am trying to backup the server to a [Synology DS212j NAS](http://www.synology.com/en-us/products/overview/DS212j).

```
Requirements:

 1. keep the files for atleast one month (1 month retention)
 2. Schedule weekly and Monthly backups which i cannot find in the GUI
```

How do i plan retention policy for my backups. This was supported in Server 2003, how could this go missing in a far more advanced Server OS? I have checked the CLI commands, but cannot find any or even if this is even possible. Can some Windows Backup Command line script help me turn on Retention Settings.
[image: Backup Retention]

Also, can i schedule it for once every 2 days?
[image: Backup Schedule]

Every help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i was able to schedule backups on a monthly and weekly basis using [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).
Scheduled a weekly task to run this batch script:

```
WBADMIN START BACKUP -backupTarget:\\fileserver\share -include:C: -quiet >> C:\backuplogs.txt
```

Links that helped:
[Configure Automatic Backups with Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834883.aspx), [How to backup Windows Scheduled Tasks](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ce29bd1d-2343-412b-8ebd-d3fa699fc433/how-to-backup-windows-scheduled-tasks?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Hope this helps.
But, i'm still stuck at the **retention settings** part.